# Config for multiple SSL Certificates on Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to configure multiple ssl certificates for application load balancer directly in my eb extensions file but impossible to set multiple ARN, below my config:

```
- namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
  option_name: SSLCertificateArns
  value: 'arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:xxx' # or 'arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:xxx,arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:yyy'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbv2-listener-default > SSLCertificateArns accepts only one ARN

I tried to separate arn by comma in value but I have this error

```
Updating Load Balancer listener named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:xxx failed Reason: Up to '1' certificate ARNs can be specified, but '2' were specified (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: TooManyCertificates; Request ID: xxx
```

I can add SSL certificate manually but on every deployment a new environment is created (and an application load balancer) so my config is lost.

Did you find a way to fix this? or a workaround?

Comment: AWS load balancers do NOT support multiple SSL certificates. What are your trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes it's supported now https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/

Comment: Thank you. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to AWS Support, here a workaround waiting the official implementation: create an ebextensions config file like this:

```
Resources:
    AddingSSLCert2:
        Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerCertificate"
        Properties:
            ListenerArn: { "Ref" : "AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener443" }
            Certificates:
                - CertificateArn: "your-arn"
```

Comment: If you get Stack named '...' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AddingSSLCert2] make sure the cert is on the same region as your load balancer. As a troubleshooting tip, create a new environment with the additional arn as the only cert to get better error messages